# Trimming a data entry into a text box in Access automatically after original entry

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a simple Access database that has image pathways identified by part numbers. Right now people can enter the part number manually but I want them to be able to scan a barcode that enters the part number. Unfortunately, the barcode contains additional content other than the part number.

For example: 79|99999-ID|Lot:9999|Exp:31-June-1999

Should be trimmed down to "99999-ID".

````
Option Explicit  

Private Sub BTN_Search_Click()  
Dim SQL As String  

SQL = "SELECT Query65.ITEM_NUMBER, Query65.PLANNER_DESCRIPTION " _  
    & "From Query65 " _  
    & "WHERE [ITEM_NUMBER] = '" & Me.txtPartNumber & "' " _  
    & "ORDER BY Query65.ITEM_NUMBER "  

Me.SubPlannerSubForm.Form.RecordSource = SQL  
Me.SubPlannerSubForm.Form.Requery  

End Sub```
````

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Public Function SplitBarcodeToPartNo(ByVal Barcode As String) As String
    SplitBarcodeToPartNo = Split(Barcode, "|")(1)
End Function
Private Sub TestSplitBarcodeToPartNo()
    Debug.Print SplitBarcodeToPartNo("79|99999-ID|Lot:9999|Exp:31-June-1999")
End Sub
```

`Split()`splits the string to an Array at the `|` and as the PartNo is the second item just fetch it by Array-Index 1 (As the first is`Split(Barcode, "|")(0)`, Last (Date) is Index 3 (fourth item) )

Any reason not to store the other infos in the DB as they are scanned allready?

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your input. I should have added some more details. None of the information needs to be stored, this function is only for retrieving the data. I am a beginner at VB and all coding, here is the function that I have currently for retrieving the data.

Comment: Then please take the [tour] where the basics are explained. Comments have limited format option. So put the Code in your Question (edit and read how to format and highlight codewith markdown), then delete the comments with it. Even you just want to retrive the PartNo, you should consider storing the addition infos (if not allready there) as they can be useful later (esp- ExpDate) and you get them for free.