# Using Split function to Trim a data entry for searching purposes in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a simple Access database that has image pathways identified by part numbers. Right now people can enter the part number manually but I want them to be able to scan a barcode that enters the part number. Unfortunately, the barcode contains additional content other than the part number.

For example: 79|99999-ID|Lot:9999|Exp:31-June-1999

Should be trimmed down to "99999-ID".

````
Option Explicit  

Private Sub BTN_Search_Click()  
Dim SQL As String  

SQL = "SELECT Query65.ITEM_NUMBER, Query65.PLANNER_DESCRIPTION " _  
    & "From Query65 " _  
    & "WHERE [ITEM_NUMBER] = '" & Me.txtPartNumber & "' " _  
    & "ORDER BY Query65.ITEM_NUMBER "  

Me.SubPlannerSubForm.Form.RecordSource = SQL  
Me.SubPlannerSubForm.Form.Requery  

End Sub```
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trimming a data entry into a text box in Access automatically after original entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165155/trimming-a-data-entry-into-a-text-box-in-access-automatically-after-original-ent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need something like this, if the user still should be able to enter the part number manually:

```
Private Sub BTN_Search_Click() 

    Dim SQL As String 
    Dim PartNumber As String

    If UBound(Split(Me.txtPartNumber, "|") > 0 Then
        ' Barcode.
        PartNumber = Split(Me.txtPartNumber, "|")(1)
    Else
        ' Manual entry.
        PartNumber = Me.txtPartNumber
    End If

    SQL = "SELECT Query65.ITEM_NUMBER, Query65.PLANNER_DESCRIPTION " _  
        & "From Query65 " _  
        & "WHERE [ITEM_NUMBER] = '" & PartNumber & "' " _  
        & "ORDER BY Query65.ITEM_NUMBER "  

    Me.SubPlannerSubForm.Form.RecordSource = SQL  
    Me.SubPlannerSubForm.Form.Requery  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your barcode is in `Me.txtPartNumber` and has fixed format and required part located at the same place, you can use the `Split` function like this:

```
Split(Me.txtPartNumber,"|")(1)
```